# How to make half a photo negative

Tags: image, jython, jes

I have my code to negative out a photo but I am struggling trying to figure out how to negate only half either the left side or the rigth side of the image. Below is the code for negative that I know I can't figure out how to get half the pixels I need.

```
def negative(picture):
  for px in getPixels(picture):
      red=getRed(px)
      green=getGreen(px)
      blue=getBlue(px)
      negColor=makeColor(255-red,255-green,255-blue)
      setColor(px, negColor)
```

Answer (score 0):

First off you need to find the width of the picture and divide that by 2

```
halfWidth = getWidth(picture) / 2
```

Because you don't want to iterate through all the pixels you can't use `for px in getPixels(picture):`. What you will need is the `range()` function in conjunction with 2 `for` loops such as

```
# Iterate along the Y axis
for y in range(0, getHeight(picture)):

  # Iterate along the X axis but only for half the width
  for x in range(0, halfWidth):

    # Get the pixel at X, Y coordinate from picture
    px = getPixel(picture, x ,y)
```

The rest of your code should work with this.